# i need to change to layout of the buttons and the counter

Tags: css, reactjs

counter.js

```
import "./Counter.css";
const Counter = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="counter">
      <h1>{`Counter ${props.count}`}</h1>
      <div className="counter__buttons">
        <button onClick={props.incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
        <button onClick={props.decrementCounter}>Decrement</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Counter.css

```
.counter {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.counter > .counter__buttons > button {
  color: black;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

[image]

i want to move the buttons below counter and place the counter and buttons in the center of the page how to change it , display : flex in counter should not be removed

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? You can set the flex-direction of a wrapping `div` to column and set the second `div` (in your case your buttons) back to `flex-direction: row` and finally just center it with `margin: 0 auto`.

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="one">1</div>
  <div id="two">2
    <div id="three">3</div>
    <div id="four">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```css
.page {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
 }

.counter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* add this */
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  /* width: 100%;*/
  /* height: 100%;*/
}

.counter > .counter__buttons > button {
  color: black;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">    
  <div class="counter">
      <h1>Counter 5</h1>
      <div class="counter__buttons">
        <button onClick={props.incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
        <button onClick={props.decrementCounter}>Decrement</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If so, you can make your whole page a flex container and use `justify-content` and `align-items` just like you did it for the `.counter`.

(I did HTML instead of JSX so I could add the snippet easier... don't forget to make changes in your own code)